# How to implement a 3D slider on Owl-carousel 2?

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I want to make such a slider on Owl-carousel, but not knowing how to implement it, I found this example https://codepen.io/Webevasion/pen/EPMGQe

[image]

But the problem is that for some reason the code from this example does not work for me. Apparently because this is the code of the old version of owl-carousel and perhaps the solution lies in afterAction, but what was it replaced with in the second version?

My code

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.gallery').owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:0,
      responsiveClass:true,
      items:7,
      center: true,
      nav: true,
      navText : ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
      onDragged: callback
      
    });
    
    $(".center").next().addClass("near");
    $(".center").prev().addClass("near");
    
    $(".center").nextAll().eq(1).addClass("next");
    $(".center").prevAll().eq(1).addClass("next");
    
    $(".center").nextAll().eq(2).addClass("last");
    $(".center").prevAll().eq(2).addClass("last");
    
    $(".center").nextAll().eq(3).addClass("lastest");
    $(".center").prevAll().eq(3).addClass("lastest");
    
}); 

function callback(event) {
    
     $(".owl-item").removeClass("near");
     $(".owl-item").removeClass("next");
     $(".owl-item").removeClass("last");
     $(".owl-item").removeClass("lastest");
     
     $(".center").next().addClass("near");
     $(".center").prev().addClass("near");
     
     $(".center").nextAll().eq(1).addClass("next");
     $(".center").prevAll().eq(1).addClass("next");
    
     $(".center").nextAll().eq(2).addClass("last");
     $(".center").prevAll().eq(2).addClass("last");
     
     $(".center").nextAll().eq(3).addClass("lastest");
     $(".center").prevAll().eq(3).addClass("lastest");
}
```

```css
.gallery .owl-item {
    transform: scale(0.8) !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.gallery .owl-item.active.center {
    transform: scale(1) !important;
}

.gallery .owl-item.near {
    transform: scale(0.7) !important;
}

.gallery .owl-item.next {
    transform: scale(0.6) !important;
}

.gallery .owl-item.last {
    transform: scale(0.5) !important;
}

.gallery .owl-item.lastest {
    transform: scale(0.4) !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="screenshots">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>Take a look at our screenshots</h3>
            <p>Everyone’s reasons for learning user interface design are different. If you’re already a developer, or a PM, or a UX designer, why develop this totally separate skill?</p>
          
<div class="gallery owl-carousel">
        <img src="img/sliders/1.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/2.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/3.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/4.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/5.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/6.png">
                          <img src="img/sliders/7.png">
/div>
</div>
</div>
  
</section>
```

code is completely jsfiddle.net/kzcbdLjs/

site itself tempes74.beget.tech

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65870416/8620333

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the dollar sign `.ready(function($)`